# Mac, Qt 4.8.6 codesign issue

Tags: macos, qt4, code-signing

I'm maintaining an old app on Mac that built with Qt 4.8.6 (It was using phonon so I can't upgrade to Qt 5.x). After building, I got an .app file, then I run `macdeployqt` on this .app to deploy Qt libraries to this. It run well. Then I need to `codesign` this .app. As I know, there are some issues relative to directory structure of the app bundle has changed and the Qt4 macdeployqt command does not conform to the new layout. I tried to fix:
`cp /Library/Frameworks/phonon.faramework/Contents/Info.plist myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/phonon.framework/Resources/`
The same for others libraries/frameworks. (copy ...{Qt}/Contents/Info.plist to myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/*.framework/Resources/
Then `codesign`, got ouput: signed bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
Then verify, got output: embedded framework contains modified or invalid version
In subcomponent ...

I searched many time on internet but cannot found the solution. How to codesign/verify this kind of bundle app? (With Qt 4.8.6. With Qt 5.x, every things is ok)
Thanks!

Comment: You could just not use *macdeployqt*, instead do the same thing manually, so the files go to right places. On Windows it would be just copying the right files, not sure if on Mac you need other tools or something, but it should still be doable, there's no magic involved I'm sure.

Comment: Is this a duplicate, or at least useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952111/unable-to-sign-app-bundle-using-qt-frameworks-on-os-x-10-10

Answer (score 0):

I have a Mac app built with Qt 4.8.7, here's the instructions I wrote to myself to get through the code signing procedure:

> Run 'macdeployqt' to copy the Qt frameworks into the bundle:
>
> ```
> $ macdeployqt myapp.app -verbose=2 -no-plugins
> ```
>
> macdeployqt doesn't work right, the frameworks need to be fixed.
>
> Go into the root of the app bundle ('cd myapp.app') and run fix_frameworks
>
> ```
> $ cd myapp.app
> $ ../../platform_specific/mac/fix_frameworks.sh
> ```
>
> Then you'll need to copy the Info.plist manually into each framework:
>
> ```
> $ cp /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/lib/QtCore.framework/Contents/Info.plist "myapp.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Resources/"
> $ cp /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/lib/QtGui.framework/Contents/Info.plist "myapp.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Resources/"
> $ cp /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Contents/Info.plist "myapp.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Resources/"
> ```
>
> Next you'll need to sign the .app with the Developer ID certificate and
>   sandbox entitlements. Get the certificate from the Mac Developer site, I
>   believe you need to log in as the Team Agent (the one who created the
>   account). On the current OS X release (Yosemite, El Cap, whatever),
>   do the following to sign the frameworks and app:
>
> ```
> $ codesign --entitlements ../platform_specific/mac/sandbox.entitlements -s "Developer ID Application" --deep myapp.app
> ```
>
> spctl should show the application is properly signed:
>
> ```
> $ spctl --verbose=4 --assess --type execute myapp.app/
> myapp.app/: accepted
> source=Developer ID
> ```

And here's the contents of `fix_frameworks.sh`

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
>
> # Run this from the root of the app bundle after running macdeployqt
>
> cd Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework
> mv Resources/ Versions/4
> cd Versions
> ln -s 4 Current
> cd ..
> ln -s Versions/Current/QtCore QtCore
> ln -s Versions/Current/Resources Resources
> cd ../../../
>
> cd Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework
> mv Resources/ Versions/4
> cd Versions
> ln -s 4 Current
> cd ..
> ln -s Versions/Current/QtGui QtGui
> ln -s Versions/Current/Resources Resources
> cd ../../../
>
> cd Contents/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework
> mv Resources/ Versions/4
> cd Versions
> ln -s 4 Current
> cd ..
> ln -s Versions/Current/QtNetwork QtNetwork
> ln -s Versions/Current/Resources Resources
> cd ../../../
> ```

You will probably need to make some changes: use the path to wherever the Qt frameworks are installed on your system, and add steps to handle Qt frameworks other than Core/Gui/Network.

Comment: Did you verify after codesign? I did codesign like you without error output, but when verifying, the error output.

Comment: Yes, the last `spctl` step verifies the application (like `codesign` does), and my application is correctly signed