# Unable to sign python app bundle using tcl (encodings) package on MacOS 12

Tags: python, macos, tcl, bundle, codesign

I am trying to build and sign my Python3 application under MacOS (v12 + M1).

I encounter very similar issue to
[Unable to sign app bundle using Qt frameworks on OS X 10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952111/unable-to-sign-app-bundle-using-qt-frameworks-on-os-x-10-10)

however in my case "code object is not signed at all" is referring to

`...Contents/MacOS/lib/encodings/cp1140.pyc`

which is copied to app package during the build process from:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/tcl8.6`

Actually, there could be any other references to files from encoding directory.

As far as I understand, it's not a framework and there is no .plist file there, so script and solution in the thread above is not working for re-initialing symlinks.

`--codesign-deep=y`
doesn't help.

Are there any other ideas how to fix it?

Comment: The Tcl library itself _never_ has anything to do with `.pyc` files. Those are to do with Python.

Comment: hmm... not sure I get the comment. What should I do then?